# If a page takes 1 ms to render, does that mean 1000 pages per second?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, scalability, benchmarking

If a webpage takes 1 ms to render, does that mean my application can do 1000 pages per second?

I understand it also depends on other things like db connections and locks, but in general is that a good measurement or is it actually probably more because of multi-threading capabilities of web servers and the # of cores etc?

BTW, as a side question, what kind of millisecond #'s do you guys see for your page views on rails apps?

Comment: No, because apps do more than render pages, and response time isn't necessarily linear.

Answer (score 4):

the response time of 1 request isn't certainly enough data to estimate the performance and scalability of a rails app. this first and easiest way to get a quick hint at how your app is performing, is using `ab` (apache bench).

```
ab -n 100 -c 4 http://yourdomain.com/
```

where `100` is the number of requests, and `4` is the number of concurrent requests. 
don't forget the `/` at the end! (or specify some route / controller-action you want to test)

Answer (score 3):

You definitely can't rely on linear scale, especially using low data points (or in your case, 1 data point).

This is the point of load testing - so that you can more reliably determine how your site/application will perform. By testing at predefined load intervals, you can better determine the curve at which performance declines.